# Powershell Mock a module with matching param returns null

Tags: powershell, mocking, pester

I'm attempting to use Powershell to mock Join-Path with in a module.  This mock will return a TestDrive location but I keep getting $null instead of the TestDrive location.  In my example module $OutputPath returns with null.  What am  I doing wrong with my Mock?

foo.psm1

```
function foobar {
    $OutputPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath '..\..\..\Output\'
    if (!(test-path $OutputPath) ) {
        $null = New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $OutputPath
    }
}
```

foo.Tests.ps1

```
import-module foo.psm1
Describe "Mock Example" {
    $TestLocation = New-Item -Path "TestDrive:\Output\" -ItemType Directory

    Mock -CommandName 'Join-Path' -MockWith { return $TestLocation.FullName } -ModuleName 'Foo' -ParameterFilter {$ChildPath -eq '..\..\..\Output\'}

}
```

Comment: `$TestLocation` is out of scope to your scriptblock is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine to me. I used a `Write-Host` to check what the $OutputPath value was when in the function to see it was being set to the TestDrive path. I also used `Assert-MockCalled` to verify your Mock was being invoked:

```
function foobar {
    $OutputPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath '..\..\..\Output\'
    Write-Host $OutputPath

    if (!(test-path $OutputPath) ) {
        $null = New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $OutputPath
    }
}

Describe "Mock Example" {
    $TestLocation = New-Item -Path "TestDrive:\Output\" -ItemType Directory

    Mock -CommandName 'Join-Path' -MockWith { $TestLocation } -ParameterFilter {$ChildPath -eq '..\..\..\Output\'}

    It 'Should work' {
        foobar | should -be $null
        Assert-MockCalled Join-Path
    }
}
```

Your code returns `$null` by design.

Comment: To ensure that my variable is passing through to the scriptblock should I use $Using:TestLocation?

Comment: No that’s not necessary, there isn’t a scoping issue as the write-host proves the variable is getting populated. What version of Pester are you using?